# Elasticsearch NEST, case sensitive multi-field

Tags: case, nest

I struggle to make this multi-field setting to case sensitive, what's the missing piece?
Thanks in advance!!.

```
   targetClientProperties.MapFluent< CMSDocument >
    ( m => m. MapFromAttributes() 
           .Properties( p => p.MultiField( mf => mf
                                    .Name ( n => n.Hash )
                                    .Fields(fs => fs
                                            .String(s => s.Name(t => t.PropertyHash))
                                            .String(s => s.Name(t => t.TileHash))
    ))));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the fields to `not_analyzed`:

```
targetClientProperties.MapFluent< CMSDocument >
( m => m. MapFromAttributes() 
       .Properties( p => p.MultiField( mf => mf
                                .Name ( n => n.Hash )
                                .Fields(fs => fs
                                        .String(s => s.Name(t => t.PropertyHash).Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed))
                                        .String(s => s.Name(t => t.TileHash).Index(FieldIndexOption.not_analyzed))
))));
```

Comment: Thanks!!, so it means I don't need a multi-field setting to have a case sensitive field, I already have some "not_analyzed" fields attributes, but I run "query_string" or "term" searches with case matches, I cannot find any of them, I don't understand how come, how the query should looks like?

Comment: No problem.  Yes, that is correct.  Multi fields are useful for when you want to index/search the same field in different ways.  For instance, if you wanted to facet on the exact value of a field, but still wanted to perform analysis to enable full-text search on that same field.  The Elasticsearch getting started guide does a very good job of explaining all of this, check out the [mapping and analysis](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_exact_values_vs_full_text.html) section in particular.